# Cron Cache is not working

Tags: cron, caching

When i used the Cache Expiration module i noticed that the Cron Cache module is no longer working and the cache tables in the database are no longer flushed so the database size is getting bigger day after day .
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: If you've confirmed this behavior, this sounds like something that should be reported to the Cache Expiration module's maintainers... http://drupal.org/project/issues/expire

Comment: I did, but i had no ansewer..

Comment: If you report an issue on Drupal.org related to a question here, you should link to that issue in your question.